# SWT Force Re-Draw of Label

Tags: java, swt, label

I have a simple method that sets the text of a label:

```
public void setStatus(final String status)
{
   statusLabel.setText(status);
}
```

When I call it before any sort of `Display.asyncExec(Runnable)`, it seems to not execute until after that `Runnable` has completed. I have even tried to implement it in the `Runnable`, and it doesn't work.  For example, I have a 'load file' menu item that I would like the status to display "Loading: [filename]" after a user selects a file:

```
    MenuItem mntmLoadFile = new MenuItem(menu_4, SWT.NONE);
    mntmLoadFile.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            String file = GuiWorkshop.selectFile(shell, new String[]{"*.apk"});
            if(file != null){
                try{
                    setStatus("Loading File: " + file);
                    controller.loadFile(new File(file));
                } catch (Exception e){
                    GuiWorkshop.messageError(shell, "Could not load file: " + e.getMessage());
                    logger.error("Could not load file: ", e);
                }
                clearStatus();
            }
        }
    });
    mntmLoadFile.setText("Load file");
```

The line `controller.loadFile(new File(file));` is what performs all of the loading, but the `setStatus` will never update until it has completed. Is there a way to force that to finish, prior to the next line executing? I am not sure if this is a local thread problem, or an SWT thread problem.

Comment: If you add line `statusLabel.redraw()` after setting the text String in `setStatus(...)` method, does it draw correctly? The code you provided is in main thread (is your app single threaded)?

Comment: multi threaded, but when the redraw doesnt seem to help even in single threaded portions...

Answer (score 0):

You can call `Display.readAndDispatch()` in a loop until it returns `false`.  This will ensure all redraw operations have completed.

```
...
setStatus("Loading File: " + file);

while (display.readAndDispatch())
{
   // nothing to do
}

controller.loadFile(new File(file));
...
```

Note: You probably do not want to call `controller.loadFile()` on the UI thread.  This will cause the UI to hang.  Instead, you should call `controller.loadFile()` in a background thread.  When the background thread finishes, have the UI thread update the status.

Answer (score -1):

You have to refresh the label after setting the text. The Control API (which is the superclass for all SWT components) has a method redraw(), which, calls the create contents method again and should provide the result you are looking for.

I hope this helps.